# wordpress got updated 4.7.1 to 4.7.2 on dev server but not on production

Tags: wordpress

on the production server i don't get the core update option
only the "check again" button

i have tried to define auto core update to true

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true );
```

and tried to install wordfence so it will find the problem
tried "Advanced Automatic Updates" plugin but when i go to it's setting i get error page with this message:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

nothing helped...

what else can be done?

**UPDATE - TEMP FIX THE PROBLEM**

on the production server, the client asked for limit login plugin and supplied that plugin under mu-plugin.
removing this gave back the ability to update the wp core

Comment: Besides manually update, you mean?

Comment: yes... if i take the core files and put them with out wp-content folder and wp-config.php, how will the DB know i have updated so it will fix the DB tables?

Comment: Well, I wasn't meaning to manually overwrite the files (that would be my last option) but go to `Dashboard > Updates > Update Now`